# ECLIPSE CDT With PTP MPI cannot open source file

Tags: eclipse, mpi

Hi i am in Ubuntu 13 and i have installed PTP to work with MPI in my Eclipse 3.8. Problem is after creating a project and trying to open the source file to work on it i have this message.

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.ui.editor.RemoteCEditor.getInputCElement()Lorg/eclipse/cdt/core/model/ICElement;
```

I have looked on the web but so far no results about this message, could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Just crossed this problem now.

Try using another editor, shouldn't affect the way it is compiled.

Assuming your using C/C++, you can right click on the source file in Eclipse and then select

```
Open with > C/C++ Editor
```